# Convert text to datetime, and select between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get some values between two dates (the 100 last days). However my column is a text-field, formatted: 17.06.2013

```
SELECT
.....
WHERE Organizations.OrganizationID = '4360' 
AND convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),StatisticsDate),104) BETWEEN       
    convert(datetime,GETDATE()-100,104) AND convert(datetime,GETDATE(),104) 
GROUP BY  Groups.Name, GroupStatistics.StatisticsDate
```

Mssql error:
    The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you! :-)

UPDATE:

```
[GroupStatisticsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CreateUser] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[StatisticsDate] [text] NULL,
[memberAttendants] [int] NOT NULL,
[Free] [int] NULL,
[FreeHours] [int] NULL,
[GroupName] [text] NULL,
[GroupNumber] [int] NULL,
[Ser] [text] NULL,
[SerNmbr] [int] NULL,
[SerName] [text] NULL
```

UPDATE2:
I tried `SELECT GETDATE()` which gave me: `2013-06-18 22:38:25:270`
Does that mean I need to convert to this formatting to use `BETWEEN`?

Comment: can you post your table structure with data type ?

Comment: Why are you using TEXT for the StatisticsDate?  TEXT in SQL Server is reserved for large blocks of text (up to 2GB), and therefore is not really acceptable for GROUP BY functions.  I can't really fathom a scenario where the date you're working with would need to be stored in a field that size.  Just wondering.

Comment: Hi Maurice. A newbies ignorance. And now its to complicated to change it I think. But in my next project, the date field will be date field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date comparision with between is not the problem in your case, since you casted already.

You will have to Group with Not text values:

```
GROUP BY  Name, convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),StatisticsDate),104)
```

Comment: Hi Bummi. Now I got this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: might have many reasons http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Conversion+failed+when+converting+date+and%2For+time+from+character+string